# How to manipulate a String in python? or how to get substring in python?

Tags: python-3.x, string

I am getting a string as output, string will be different all time, but the starting of the string will be having same format all time, the end would be different.

For example:

String 1: create file abc  xyz:/prjct/subdir/partIWant --admin --abc
String 2: create file abc  xyz:/test/pyhton/partIWantpartIWant titledadmin --admin source --abc

I want the below output from above both string
Output:
String 1: partIWant
String 2: partIWantpartIWant

Please kindly help me, i am beginner in python. Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the prefix string beforehand, you can do something like this. Note that thi

```py
import re
from functools import partial

def get_substr(prefix, s):
    # Remove prefix at the start, just to be safe
    s = re.sub(rf"^{prefix}", '', s)
    # Get the third URI part
    match = re.search(r"(?:\w+\/){2}(\w+).*", s)

    if match:
        return match.group(1)
    else:
        return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ss = ['create file abc xyz:/prjct/subdir/partIWant --admin --abc',
          'create file abc xyz:/test/pyhton/partIWantpartIWant titledadmin --admin source --abc']
    prefix = 'create file abc xyz:/'

    # Create a partial function; a function that always has 'prefix'
    # as its first value, and that only requires one other argument
    substr_func = partial(get_substr, prefix)
    ss_out = list(map(substr_func, ss))

    print(ss_out)
```

Comment: This works fine, but instead of using partial function i just used the regular expression after removing prefix string from original string. Thank you!